# combining two maps in plotly into a dropdown

Tags: python, plotly

```
skc = pd.DataFrame(
    ['20001', '20003', '20011',
     '20015', '20019', '20021',
     '20031', '20035', '20037',
     '20049', '20059', '20073',
     '20077', '20079', '20095',
     '20099', '20107', '20113',
     '20115', '20121', '20125',
     '20133', '20155', '20173',
     '20191', '20205', '20207'], 
    columns=['fips']
)

token = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoid3N1cHBtYyIsImEiOiJjbDA2dWNiZmEyYjRqM2lsc2hrZ2g5Z3ZrIn0.Qcm0AOjbrEP6NPJ6u-14EA'

with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)  

df = pd.read_csv('data/healthy-wealthy-wise-data.csv', dtype={'fips':'str'})
df = df.sort_values(by=['healthy_quartile'])

colorscales = [
    ((0.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,0.25)'), (1.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,0.25)')),
    ((0.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,0.5)'), (1.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,0.5)')),
    ((0.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,0.75)'), (1.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,0.75)')),
    ((0.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,1.0)'), (1.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,1.0)'))
]

fig = go.Figure()
for i, quartile in enumerate(df['healthy_quartile'].unique()):
    dfp = df[df['healthy_quartile'] == quartile]
    fig.add_choroplethmapbox(
        geojson=counties, locations=dfp['fips'],
        z=[i,] * len(dfp), featureidkey='id',
        showlegend=True, name=quartile,
        colorscale=colorscales[i], showscale=False,
        text='County:  ' + dfp['county'].str.title() +
        '<br>Quartile:  ' + dfp['healthy_quartile'].str.split(' ').str[0],
        hoverinfo='text'
    )
    
choropleth = go.Choroplethmapbox(
        geojson=counties,
        locations=df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['fips'],
        z=df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['fips'],
        zmin=0, zmax=0,
        colorscale = [[0,'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'],[1,'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)']],
        marker_line_color='rgb(255,193,0)',
        marker_line_width=2,
        showscale = False,
        text='County:  ' + df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['county'].str.title() +
        '<br>Quartile:  ' + df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['healthy_quartile'].str.split(' ').str[0],
        hoverinfo='text'
    )

fig.add_trace(choropleth)    

fig.update_layout(legend_title='Index Performance', margin={'r':0,'t':0,'l':0,'b':0},
                  mapbox_accesstoken=token,
                  mapbox=dict(style='carto-positron', zoom=6, 
                              center={'lat': 38.4937, 'lon': -98.3804},))
  
  
  
  
                              
# this section is for the second figure


fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args=["type", "surface"],
                    label="Healthy Index",
                    method="restyle"
                ),
                dict(
                    args=["type", "heatmap"],
                    label="Wealthy Index",
                    method="restyle"
                )
            ]),
            direction="down",
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.1,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.1,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
    ]
)
```

and

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['wealthy_quartile'])

colorscales = [
    ((0.0, 'rgba(231,38,40,0.25)'), (1.0, 'rgba(231,38,40,0.25)')),
    ((0.0, 'rgba(231,38,40,0.5)'), (1.0, 'rgba(231,38,40,0.5)')),
    ((0.0, 'rgba(231,38,40,0.75)'), (1.0, 'rgba(231,38,40,0.75)')),
    ((0.0, 'rgba(231,38,40,1.0)'), (1.0, 'rgba(231,38,40,1.0)'))
]

fig = go.Figure()
for i, quartile in enumerate(df['wealthy_quartile'].unique()):
    dfp = df[df['wealthy_quartile'] == quartile]
    fig.add_choroplethmapbox(
        geojson=counties, locations=dfp['fips'],
        z=[i,] * len(dfp), featureidkey='id',
        showlegend=True, name=quartile,
        colorscale=colorscales[i], showscale=False,
        text='County:  ' + dfp['county'].str.title() +
        '<br>Quartile:  ' + dfp['wealthy_quartile'].str.split(' ').str[0],
        hoverinfo='text'
    )

choropleth = go.Choroplethmapbox(
        geojson=counties,
        locations=df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['fips'],
        z=df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['fips'],
        zmin=0, zmax=0,
        colorscale = [[0,'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'],[1,'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)']],
        marker_line_color='rgb(131,201,217)',
        marker_line_width=2,
        showscale = False,
        text='County:  ' + df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['county'].str.title() +
        '<br>Quartile:  ' + df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['wealthy_quartile'].str.split(' ').str[0],
        hoverinfo='text'
    )

fig.add_trace(choropleth)     
    
fig.update_layout(legend_title='Index Performance', margin={'r':0,'t':0,'l':0,'b':0},
                  mapbox_accesstoken=token,
                  mapbox=dict(style='carto-positron', zoom=6, 
                              center={'lat': 38.4937, 'lon': -98.3804},))
```

How do I combine these so that I can switch maps using a drop down what I have right now is not working, I'm not too familiar with plotly to be able to quickly solve it, but it looks like a fairly simple problem. I'm doing this in quarto which uses R

this is how I want it to be but  both on the same drop down

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvR85.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODi7K.png)

Comment: Why the [tag:r] tag, are you implementing in both Python and R?

Comment: I'm doing this in quarto which uses R

Comment: okay, but ... the code you want to fix is in Python. If you will accept answers using R alone, then that's fine, I suggest it would be helpful to say that specifically, since it's easy to dismiss questions that are "clearly" (ahem) mis-tagged and/or looks like it is tag-spamming.

Comment: so I have to say R so that people understand that for this specific problem I won't be needing dash, that's what I've encountered a lot